# Overriding Methods - JAVA polymorphism

Tags: inheritance, polymorphism

I'm working on the following code and trying to better understand polymorphism in JAVA and I can't make sense of it. Can someone plz help?

Class AA:

```
public class AA
{
    private int _val=0;
    public AA()
    {
        _val=5; 
    }
    public AA(int val)
    {
        _val=val;
    }
    public int getVal()
    {
        return _val;
    }   
    public void setVal(int val)
    {
        _val=val;
    }   
    public String toString()
    {
        return "val=" + _val ;
    }
}
```

Class BB:

```
public class BB extends AA
{
    private String _st;
    public BB ()
{
    _st="bb"; 
}
public BB(String st, int val)
{
     super(val);
     _st=st; 
}
public String getSt()
{
   return _st;
}

public boolean equals (Object ob)
{ 
    System.out.println("Method 1");
    if ((ob != null) && (ob instanceof BB))
    {    
        if (_st.equals(((BB)ob)._st)  &&
            (getVal() == ((BB)ob).getVal()))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public boolean equals (AA ob) 
{
    System.out.println("Method 2");
    if ((ob != null) && (ob instanceof BB))
    {    
        if (_st.equals(((BB)ob)._st)  &&
        (getVal() == ((BB)ob).getVal()))
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
public boolean equals (BB ob) 
{
    System.out.println("Method 3");
    if (ob != null)
    {    
            if (_st.equals(((BB)ob)._st)  &&
            (getVal() == ((BB)ob).getVal()))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

And the tester:

```
public class Driver
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {    
        AA a1 = new AA();
        AA a2 = new BB();
        AA a3 = new AA();
        AA a4 = new BB();
        BB b1 = new BB();
        BB b2 = new BB();

        System.out.println(a4.equals(a2));
    }
}
```

- When I run the following code the method that runs is BB's equals(Object ob); and I don't understand why.
- If I get rid of the equals(Object ob) method, then the method that runs is the Object class equals.
- If I add the method equals(AA ob) to class AA then the method that actually runs is BB's equals(AA ob);

Can someone please explain to me the logic here?